# Javascript: Show Image from Json with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, base64

I have a Json that contains this:

```
[
     {
          "_id": "00000",
          "title": "",
          "genre": "fantasy",
          "year": "1999",
          "image": "photo.jpg"
     }
]
```

I use AngularJs and I want show image in my page html. This is the code:

```
<div>
    <h2>Films</h2>
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="book in lista">
            <div>
               <img ng-src="{{book.cover}}" style="width: 256px; height: 128px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my controller:

```
var modulo = angular.module('progetto', ['ngRoute']);

modulo.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'list.html',
            controller: 'listController'
        })
});

modulo.controller('listController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://.......').success(function (data) {

        $scope.lista = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.lista = "Request failed";
        });
});
```

how do I show the photo? Because the photo is a jpg. Thanks!

Comment: First at all, the property name in the json is `image` but in html you use `cover`

Comment: In the data, the image seems to be in "image" property, but in code you reference "book.cover". Use "book.image" instead?

Comment: This is not a problem...writing mistake!

Comment: @user3751473 ok. But you should have the full url to the image to show it. `ng-src="http://......./{{ book.cover }}"`

Comment: Of course I know...this code don't present error!

Comment: Then, explain, please, which kind of the error that you face?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call $scope.$apply() after every http request which are modifying the model and the new value needs to be communicated to the view.

```
lo.controller('listController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://.......').success(function (data) {

        $scope.lista = data;
        $scope.$apply();
        }).
        error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.lista = "Request failed";
            $scope.$apply();
        });
});
```